# Smoothing colour between segments in stacked bar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Say I have a stacked bar with different colour in each segment.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
dm <- diamonds %>% group_by(cut, color) %>% summarize(ave.price=mean(price))
ggplot(dm) + geom_bar(aes(x=cut, y=color, fill=ave.price), stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_continuous(low="white", high="red")
```

Is there a way to smoothe the colour transition between the segments?